# iShidden always returning YES

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

using following code

```
-(IBAction)shareMenuBtnPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self.mainMenuView setHidden:YES];
    [self.tryOnView setHidden:YES];
    [self.d3View setHidden:YES];

    if ([self.shareView isHidden] == YES)
        [shareView setHidden:NO];
    else
        [self.shareView setHidden:YES];
}
```

on first Click it shows the menu i-e         `[shareView setHidden:NO];`
but if i click again it again runs the same seq. why is isHidden not changing to NO

EDIT: Ok it seems that i have placed this code

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideAllViews)];
    //tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

with `tap.cancelsTouchesinView` it bevhaves strangely and [shareView setHidden:NO] gets called always. atm i have put commments but I can't remove `tap.cancelsTouchesinView.` what should be done?

Comment: Well there is nothing wrong with your code that I can see, so the issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: maybe shareView and self.shareView are different? Why do you use ivar in one case and property in another?

Comment: Don't do a check against YES, cause it can result in false negatives. always go for if (self.shareView.isHidden) {} or if (!self.shareView.isHidden) {} because BOOL is infact typedef unsigned char. Might not solve your problem, but worth giving a try.

Comment: @JeslyVarghese yes i tried that already. Check the edit part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to write below code...

```
  if ([self.shareView isHidden] == YES)
    [shareView setHidden:NO];
else
    [self.shareView setHidden:YES];
```

instead write below code...

```
self.shareView.hidden = !self.shareView.hidden;
```

i think it will help you a lot...

Let me know it is working or not my friend!!!!!

Happy Coding....